# Get-Record-API request not working any more

Tags: algorithm, api, debugging, apify

since last week, the Get-Record API-Endpoint is not working any more. Please check out the node.js snippet and the screenshot at the end.

Getting the list of keys in the store is working (first request). But getting the records, results in chaos (second request). It's the same result, if an explizit 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' is added. Could you please verify?

Cheers Wulfgäääng

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const storeUrl = 'https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/z9UOmIgYF7oMxXkGS/';

(async () => {

    var results = await request({uri: `${storeUrl}keys`, json: true});
    console.log('Keys:');
    console.dir(results);

    results = await request({uri: `${storeUrl}records/testkey`, json: true});
    console.log('Record:');
    console.dir(results);

})();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the response returns gzipped body. It is an issue on Apify API. You can force gzip headers using gzip: true parameter in your request like:

EDIT: It was fixed on Apify site. You need to add disableRedirect=true parameter to request URL as well.

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const storeUrl = 'https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/z9UOmIgYF7oMxXkGS/';

(async () => {

    var results = await request({uri: `${storeUrl}keys`, json: true, resolveWithFullResponse: true});
    console.log('Keys:');
    console.dir(results.headers);

    results = await request({uri: `${storeUrl}records/testkey?disableRedirect=true`, json: true, gzip: true });
    console.log('Record:');
    console.dir(results.headers);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

great, it's working.

Unfortunatelly, I am not using node.js for my purpose (a local watchdog). I am using Autohotkey, which takes advantage of Windows 'WinHttpRequest.5.1' (see below).

Do you know, who to force 'WinHttpRequest.5.1' using 'gzip' decoding? 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' doesn't work either (see below).

Cheers Wulfgäääng

```
storeUrl := "https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/z9UOmIgYF7oMxXkGS/"

whr1 := ComObjCreate( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
whr1.Open("GET", storeUrl . "keys", true)
whr1.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
whr1.Send()
whr1.WaitForResponse()
response := whr1.ResponseText

whr2 := ComObjCreate( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
whr2.Open("GET", storeUrl . "records/testkey", true)
whr2.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
whr2.Send()
whr2.WaitForResponse()
response := whr2.ResponseText
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know WIN req client. 
Try to find other thread with the corresponding issue. But you need to add Accept-Encoding: "gzip" and it will work.
I will let you know about the fix, I think we will deploy it during a day.

Comment: You can try one more thing to add parameter disableRedirect=true into URL. You can check more about the parameter here -> https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/key-value-stores/record/get-record

Comment: It was fixed on Apify, but you need to still add disableRedirect=true param to request URL.